# Having an issue with timestamps from my oracle server being in different format on different clients despite

Tags: vb.net, oracle, datetime, timestamp, driver

Having an issue with vb.net clients interpreting timestamps from my oracle 11g server differently. I am using VS2010, VB.NET, 11.2.0.30 driver, Win XP on the client machines.

the software is identical on both machines, and the users have the same permissions on the server.

When I login through toad with each users credentials and do a SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL; I get YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS format.

through my application when i do a SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL; 
PC1: DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS 
PC2: YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS

I did change my serverside settings to use the YYYY-MM-DD 24HH:MI:SS format
Why is the setting being overruled on only some of the pcs? and how can i get it consistent for all clients?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Each client has its own [`NLS_DATE_FORMAT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#i1006817) setting, which might be set somewhere visible (e.g. in Toad), or might be defaulted by the platform or driver, and might be inherited indirectly through locale settings. Having `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` overridden by default is less common I think, but I'm not sure if you're referring to Oracle `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE`, which also has a time component.

The client setting always overrides the server setting, so changing the server is unlikely to help, and you might just have some clients that are already set with a matching format. The client setting can itself be explicitly overridden after you connect at session level with an `alter session` command, or individually in SQL statements. The precedence is shown in the [globalization support guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#i1005949).

In general you should never rely on implicit data conversions. Other than in simple ad hoc queries, date are normally selected for display using an explicit [date format](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#autoId2) mask, e.g. `select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual`. If you have an application that expects a date to be returned (as a string) in a particular format then it's safer to do that... though normally you'd pull a `DATE` back and let the client do the formatting anyway.

It's arguably even more important to always specify a format mask when inserting data from a string with a `to_date()` call, but again your client would normally handle that and pass a `DATE`.

Comment: so, I used a set of alter session statements to ensure that everyones nls parameters were identical. Unfortunately the issue remains. as you alluded to, it might be better to have it returned as a string rather than a date format. In my previous project I cast dates into string because VB.NET tends to want to reformat every date erratically. Guess I will have to go back to that practice.

Comment: @A.Cottrill - I think I misunderstood. If you're retrieving it from Oracle as a `DATE`, then the NLS parameters don't matter, unless there's an implicit conversion during the retrieval. If you have something a `getDate()` call and you VB variable is a `Date` (sorry, haven't used VB for years, can't remember the lingo) then I guess this is a formatting issue with *VB's* default as it prepares it for display, so maybe you need to use `Format`, or pass the format you want to `ToString()`?